# Find long SHA from short SHA for git diff

Tags: git, diff, sha, review-board

I was generating difference / changes done in the commit so that I can upload it in ReviewBoard.

I used "git show d9f7121e8ebd4d1f789dab9f8214ada2h480b9cf". It gave me diff something like...

```
diff --git a/src/index.php b/src/index.php
index 3cfa8e8..7f8440d 100644
--- a/src/index.php
+++ b/src/index.php
@@ -12,10 +12,13 @@
 .test {
     .input;
     width: auto;
+    border-width: 5px;
+    border-radius: 50%;
 }
```

When I create .patch file of this diff. Reviewboard rejects it saying "'3cfa8e8' revision is not valid format. SHA1 is too short".

So I wanted to get long SHA1 from short SHA1 '3cfa8e8'.

I did 'git show 3cfa8e8'. It just shows me some content of file. Doesn't show me anything else.

Any help how can I get long SHA?

(Note:- All the sha and file diff are example to demonstrate the problem)

Answer (score 15):

`git rev-parse <short sha>` should do the trick.

See also the [`git rev-parse` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse).